# How do I get the array response to save to a text file

Tags: angular

How do I get the array response to save to a text file

**my.component.ts**

```
fileUrl;
  ngOnInit() {
      this.loadMovies();
      const data = this.api.getYeah();
      const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/json' });
      this.fileUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  }

  /* API call*/
  getYeah(): Observable<any> {
  const endpoints = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
  return this.http.get(endpoints).pipe(
        map(this.extractData));
 }
```

**my.component.html**

```
<a [href]="fileUrl" download="file.txt">DownloadFile</a>
```

Okay so what I want to do is save an array into a txt file with the click of a button how it works is when the download button is clicked the api makes a call and the response data is saved into a txt file but the txt file just says object in it and Ive no idea why can anyone see why

Comment: I think you forgot to subscribe to observable please check answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think here you forgot to subscribe to observable. So you need to subscribe observable like below then you will get the response from the server which you can pass to Blob object like below

**Example -**

```
 ngOnInit() {

    this.api.getYeah().subscribe((response) => { 
         let data = JSON.stringify(response);
         const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/json' });
         this.fileUrl = this.sanitizer.
              bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob))
    }
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Its still printing object in the file and not the array

Comment: and if you want to convert again then use JSON.parse(data) it will return array of objects

Comment: I'm glad, I could help!

Answer (score 0):

> Use JSON.stringify

```
const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], { type: 'application/json' });
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the returned array